# wicket.version.undo package in Wicket 7.6.0

Tags: java, eclipse, import, wicket, undo

I am learning how to use wicket. I found [this example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077866/open-source-tools/web-development-with-wicket--part-1--the-state-of-wicket.html), which I am trying to implement, but I`ve stumbled upon a problem with **wicket.version.undo** package. In the example, **Change** class from this package is used for pages versioning.
But when I try to import this package I get an error: *The import can not be resolved*
So I was wondering whether this package was replaced with something else in newer versions of the wicket? (*my version is 7.6.0*). Because I have found the jar of this package only for up to 1.6 versions.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is very old!

The easiest way to solve such kind of issues is to remove the import from the code. This way the IDE will try to find the missing classes for you. If the classes are not available on the current classpath then modern IDEs will try to find it in Maven Central and suggest you to add another dependecy to the class path.

I don't have the IDE in front of me but I think the classes you need are in wicket-util module.

Comment: I'm working through the same issue while migrating from older version of wicket. I have found no direct replacement for this particular class: org.apache.wicket.version.undo.Change. Instead should implement stateful pages as described in the guide: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_page_versioning_and_caching 

I'm still trying to fully understand how to get the exact same behavior as Change.undo() provided.